# AVG linkscanner alert when trying to review

Tags: support, security

I was trying to review posts on "reopen votes" when I got the following:

[image]

Have you ever seen this before? How can I fix this? The site tells me there was an error trying to pull the next reopen vote.

Note: When I try to review other categories such as "close votes" or "first posts" everything works just fine. I've tried reopen votes twice and got this alert in both.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that your are using AVG

Comment: Is there anything we should be aware of? maybe a server hack or something? I believe the owners should be aware.

Comment: There's probably just some text in the post it's attempting to load that AVG is flagging as a threat and blocking. AVG is just giving you a false positive.

Comment: @animuson I figured it was something like this. thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just because the next review item was a question that contained code from that exploit:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625929/the-hacker-insert-that-script-in-my-code-what-is-it-about

There was no actual danger, AVG just misidentified the threat as being part of the page, and it won't happen again unless a similar post pops up in the queue.

Comment: Nice forensics How can you tell which one is the next edit?

Comment: So AVG did its job, if only a bit zealously.

Comment: @raam86 Since the item had already been processed, I just looked at the history for that review queue for the last post, which was pretty clearly the culprit.

Comment: Yep. it's funny that I use AVG for quite some time now and the first time I ran into this was in SO

Comment: @Makoto my nemesis!! ;)

Comment: @Makoto Right, which you can't *really* fault it for, since it doesn't easily know if the browser will attempt to execute the payload.

Comment: @TimStone well it seems to me that AVG is trying to parse HTML with regexes.